# Spring Boot Change RabbitListener queue name with RefreshScope Annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, microservices, spring-cloud

I'm using rabbitmq for messaging and spring cloud config server for config. I'm using rabbitlistener for consuming and keeping queue name in config server. When i change queuename on config server i want RabbitListener to change queuename but it doesn't seem to work. How can I get @rabbitlistener to change queuename when I refresh application through actuator refresh.

```
@Component
@RefreshScope
public class Listener
{
    @RabbitListener(queues="${mq.queue}")
    public void listen(@Payload Message message)
    {
        
    }
}
```